# Run ktr remotly using on pentaho BI server

Tags: pentaho

I'm using pentaho BI server 7 EE.
I have uploaded a simple transformation (.ktr) and run it successfully throught PUC.

But when I try to call it throught REST service (http://localhost:8080/pentaho/kettle/runTrans?trans=%3Apublic%3Ademo%3AsimplePdiJob.ktr) it fails with the following response:

```
<webresult>
  <result>ERROR</result>
  <message>&#x21;RunTransServlet.Error.UnexpectedError&#x21;</message>
  <id/>
</webresult>
```

I didn't find any exception in the log.
What can be the cause of this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I do not know if you still have this problem but I managed to solve it these days doing an xaction and inserting in the  in the XML code that I inserted a PHP script that made the call of my .ktr file and uploaded to the server a file Csv that was with which I would perform my ETL. I know that is not the best solution but for my case there is no way even in version 7 of bi server to upload csv files or some other extension.